# If there are M different boxes and N identical balls

Tags: math, combinatorics

and we need to put these balls into boxes.

How many states of the states could there be?

This is part of a computer simulation puzzle.   I've almost forget all my math knowledges.

Comment: Do each box need to have a least one ball in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [Multinomial Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).
I will check myself and expand my answer.

**Edit:**
If you take a look at the wikipedia article I gave a link to, you can see that the `M` and `N` you defined in your question correspond to the `m` and `n` defined in the [Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem) section.

This means that your question corresponds to: *"What is the number of possible coefficient orderings when expanding a polynomial raised to an arbitrary power?"*, where `N` is the power, and `M` is the number of variables in the polynomial.

**In other words:**
What you are looking for is to sum over the multinomial coefficients of a polynomial of `M` variables expanded when raised to the power on `N`.

The exact equations are a bit long, but they are explained very clearly in wikipedia.

**Why is this true:**
The multinomial coefficient gives you the number of ways to order identical balls between baskets when grouped into a specific grouping (for example, 4 balls grouped into 3, 1, and 1 - in this case M=4 and N=3). When summing over all grouping options you get all  possible combinations.

I hope this helped you out.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the game here, but the original question was about identical balls, whereas that wiki link says the multinomial coefficient can be interpreted as "the number of ways of depositing n distinct objects into m distinct bins".

Answer (score 3):

[These notes](http://www.johndcook.com/TwelvefoldWay.pdf) explain how to solve the "balls in boxes" problem in general: whether the balls are labeled or not, whether the boxes are labeled or not, whether you have to have at least one ball in each box, etc.

Answer (score 2):

this is  a basic combinatorial  question (distribution of identical objects  into non identical slots)

the number of states is  **[(N+M-1) choose (M-1)]**

Comment: If M=2 and N=2 there are three states: [({o,o},{}), ({o},{o}), ({}, {o,o})]. Your formula gives one.

Comment: No this isn't it, this is the number of way M - 1 identical balls can be selected from a group N - 1 balls.

Comment: This is correct.  But can you give some clue on how to get this equation?